# Oracle standard edition and realtime pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

As mentionned in Oracle documention: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm#DBLIC116,

Asynchronous change data capture is not available in Oracle Standard Edition.

So the question is : is "realtime pipeline" (vs batch pipeline) mode working with Oracle Standard Edition in Google Cloud Data Fusion ?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Data Fusion currently does not support this capability. However, there are plans to support it, if the oracle instance has GoldenGate or LogMiner enabled.